# oracle database : index over 10% of records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table X which is really huge in size . Daily 1 million recods are inserted in this table. I have to add an index over one of the columns of the table. But if i do so, following impact  can occur.

1. insert,update,delete might be slow.
2. additional disk space.
3. index will be update for each DML statement.
4. unforeseen issue.
5. there are already many other indexes present on table X.

So my index wont add any value, instead it will create more trouble.

I have thought of a way to come out of this situation.
But i dont know if it is achievable or not. Kindly suggest.

I want to create index only on top 10% records in the table. 
And that query should maintain that in future also its 10% only.

Comment: Break up your data into two tables, recent and old.  Add the index to the old data.

Comment: Is your table patitionized?

Comment: You might need to specify what you mean by "the top 10% records". How do you determine which records are in the top 10%?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit No my table does not have any partition.

Comment: I would consider top 10% based on timestamp.Most recent Records would be on top is what my target is.

Comment: You are really still using Oracle 10?

Answer (score 2):

If your table is really "huge" (in one of my applications I add 1 billion rows per day) then you should use partitioning. I assume most of your problems would be solved by this.

Actually my answer is not valid as you don't use partitioning and use of stone-age Oracle 10g, however I tell you anyway.

In version 12c Oracle introduced [Partial Indexes for Partitioned Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-256BA7EE-BF49-42DE-9B38-CD2480A73129.htm#VLDBG14102). With this feature you can define indexes on single partitions.

Syntax is like this:

```
CREATE INDEX MY_INDEX ON MY_TABLE (IND_COLS) INDEXING PARTIAL;
```

You can also turn off/on indexing on existing indexes:

```
ALTER INDEX MY_INDEX INDEXING PARTIAL/FULL;
```

Then you can disable/rebuild indexes per partition like

```
ALTER INDEX MY_INDEX MODIFY PARTITION P_123 UNUSABLE;
ALTER INDEX MY_INDEX REBUILD PARTITION P_123;
```

Indexing is controlled by table partition, so before you create any index you should set default off, otherwise each newly created partition will have "indexing on".

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE MODIFY DEFAULT ATTRIBUTES INDEXING OFF;
```